# gwt-maps v3 - how to add mouseDown event handler in gwt

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

Anyone know how I can capture mouseDown and mouseUp events from the MapWidget?

I had some previous code in gwt maps v2 that looked like this:

```
addMouseDownHandler(this, map.getDraggableObject());
public native void  addMouseDownHandler(MapViewImpl callback, DraggableObject obj) /*-{
    $wnd.GEvent.addListener(obj, "mousedown", function(event) {
        callback.@org.gt.application.gwt.client.map.view.MapViewImpl::mouseDown(II)(event.x, event.y);
    });
}-*/;
```

This doesn't work anymore.  GEvent doesn't look to be defined nor DraggableObject.   I don't see any apis in MapWidget for addMouseDown either.   Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try `Widget.addDomHandler` :

```
MapOptions options = MapOptions.newInstance();
final MapWidget map = new MapWidget(options);
map.addDomHandler(new MouseDownHandler() {

    public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
        Window.alert("test");

    }
}, MouseDownEvent.getType());
```

I get the alert in hosted mode. `map.addClickHandler` works as well.

Comment: Can we get name of the place where we have clicked?